# Uploading NSData image via POST in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, post

i have a form that contains some person information and an image. i tried to save information in post using this function and it work well :

```
    - (void)Inscription:(NSArray *)value completion:(void (^)( NSString * retour))block{


        NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];   
        NSArray *Param_header = @[@"username", @"password", @"email",@"first_name", @"last_name",@"image"];    
       // NSArray *Param_value = @[@"ali", @"aliiiiiiii", @"ali.ali@gmail.com",@"ali",@"zzzzz"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://  /Messenger/services/messenger_register"]]];     
        NSString *aa=[self buildParameterWithPostType:@"User" andParameterHeaders:Param_header ansParameterValues:value];    
        [request setHTTPBody:[aa dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];      
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];      
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: request
                                           queue: queue
                               completionHandler: ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                                   if (error || !data) {
                                       // Handle the error

                                       NSLog(@"Server Error : %@", error);
                                   } else {

                                       NSError *error = Nil;      
                                       id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];       
                                       block([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [jsonObjects objectForKey:@"message"]]);        

                                   }   
                               }     
         ];        

    }
```

No, i want to send the photo taked, i convert it to NSData first :

```
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    UIImage *imag= [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    imag = [imag scaleAndRotateImage:imag];


    CGFloat compression = 0.9f;
    CGFloat maxCompression = 0.1f;
    int maxFileSize = 25*1024;//was 250x1024

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imag, compression);

    while ([imageData length] > maxFileSize && compression > maxCompression)
    {
        compression -= 0.1;
        imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imag, compression);
    }

   NSData _D_ImageData = imageData;
```

And i tried to do this to send it to server but image c'ant be uploaded:

```
 [web Inscription:Param_value completion:^(NSString *retour) {
        CustomPrpgress.hidden=true;
        NSLog(@" eee %@ ",retour);
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:retour message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];

    }];
```

Can someone help me, i'm beginner and this is my first time. thank you

Comment: My code work fine, i made a mistake in the php file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code work fine, i made a mistake in the php file